# Safari glitch with jQuery continuous animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation, safari, jquery-animate

I'm developing a jQuery plugin composed by sliding boxes and having the continuous slide option (a sort of news stream). Everything is perfect on Firefox, Chrome, Opera, IE, iOS but (windows) Safari has huge problems with the continuous slider.

As soon as I move the curson in the browser I get strange glitches, black boxes and if I trigger another navigation command everything is blocked with [this result](http://jsfiddle.net/PsnS3/18/) and I have to restart the browser.!

The code I use to animate the box is this

```
     $.fn.animate_pos = function(side, val, duration, easing) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $obj = $(this);
            if(typeof(easing) == 'undefined') {easing = 'swing';}

            $({Slide : start_val}).clearQueue().animate({Slide : to_val}, {
                easing: easing,
                duration: duration,
                step: function(now, fx) {
                    $obj.set_pos(side, now);
                }
            });
        });
    }


    // set object position for CSS2 or CSS3
    $.fn.set_pos = function(side, val) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $obj = $(this);

            if(css3_browser) {
                if(side == 'left') {
                    $obj.css('-webkit-transform', 'translate3d('+ val +'px, 0px, 0px)');    
                    $obj.css('transform', 'translate3d('+ val +'px, 0px, 0px)');    
                } else {
                    $obj.css('-webkit-transform', 'translate3d(0px, '+ val +'px, 0px)');    
                    $obj.css('transform', 'translate3d(0px, '+ val +'px, 0px)');        
                }
            }
            else {
                $obj.css(side, val);
            }
        });
    }
```

The plugin uses also CSS3 effects. I've already tried to remove any CSS3 code and use the animation on the "position" attribute, but the result is the same.

Anyone experienced the same? Looks like a Safari bug handling animations.

Code sample at http://jsfiddle.net/PsnS3/18/

Comment: Providing a fiddle would be great help!

Comment: Sure, it took a lot to simulate a mini system (my one is very complex). This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PsnS3/18/

Since it works seamlessly, I think there's something related to other elements. Anyway, any code suggestion would be helpful

Comment: I'm sorry but i cannot reproduce the error in Safari Version 7.0 (9537.71) / OSX Mavericks

Comment: After 5 hours of tests I probably found the solution. The sliding elements container must be without `overflow` CSS rule. Probably forcing the `visible` parameter caused the Safari bug.

Finally I used a translate3d to animate another element in the same wrapper and also that was causing a minor "black" artifact. Using common CSS2 animations the issue disappeared.

This on Safari 5.1.7 on Windows.